# Как вывести количество элементов массива структур в форме таблицы за одной из переменных структуры?

Tags: c++

Есть структура  worker, в которую входит номер цеха и возраст. Создан массив работников с разными данными. Необходимо подсчитать количество работников до 20ти лет, от 20 до 30 и более 30. Вывести в виде таблицы:

код цеха.....кол-во работников от 20ти...20-30...30+

Сложность возникла в том, что бы в таблице каждый работник не занимал новую строку с тем же кодом цеха, а добавлялся в уже существующую для его кода цеха.

```
struct worker
{
    int codePid, codeCeh, tabNum, yearBirth, codeNation, famStage, workStage, workStageNep, profCode, roz;
    double ok;
    char  surname[30];
};
int main()
{
worker w[10];
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Уточните состав элемента массива "работников". Необходимо понять по какому полю "работник" из того массива вяжется к номеру цеха.